# Issue with max_execution_time during file import in php 5.4.22

Tags: php, ini-set

PHP Version: PHP Version 5.4.22
JS :ExtJs

I'm facing to the problem below:

I've an CSV import in PHP and after about 30 to 30.5 seconds the XHR process canceled, then the browser (Chrome, Firefox) hang on and finished the process.

All the data are imported into the database. Ok, that's good but:
At the beginning and at the end of the import function i've a log-function ( Start ) and at the end ( End: XX imported files. )

The problem is, that in the database are two start and two end log entries.

I looks, that during the second start of the function these entries will be generated.

I've tried:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '12M');
```

But without an result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've change following setttings

```
remoteApi.maxRetries = 0;
remoteApi.timeout = 300000;
```

now it work perfekt!!